# How new ideas are added?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, scope

Stack Exchange is expanding by adding new topics (websites). How is the decision made about approving ideas for new sites? I think it comes from Area 51, but is it that the only source for decision-making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How the elite management decide about approving new idea

If by "idea" you mean an idea for a new site - it's purely [Area 51 driven.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/area-51-we-come-in-peace/)

> But is it the only source for decision-making?

Yes.

Comment: Is it really a perfect democracy? The first and final decision maker is online people?

Comment: @Bruce: no, the site owners have some say. They've been known to shut down underperforming sites before they've gone public, for instance.

Comment: @BruceHarris I'm not sure what you mean - it's a not single person incharge of spinning off a site.